# Cisco AIR-CAP702W-K9 enable lan ports

Tags: cisco, wifi, ios

The 702w's have four LAN ports which are disabled by default. I'm trying, on the autonomous image (15.3(3)JAB), to enable the ports. I've tried following the [official guide](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/access_point/15-3-3-JB/configuration/guide/cg_book/cg-chap-misc-spec-APs.html) from Cisco, but fail to enter configuration for the

> ap#config t
>
> Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
>
> ap(config)#lan-Port port-id 1
>
> ```
>            ^
> ```
>
> % Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

Any help would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my IOS image was too out-of-date to configure the ports. So once I upgraded the image, I could configure as per the tutorial.